# Can't seem to add Security.framework

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to use **SFHFKeychainUtils**, but I can't compile without errors. I have the following at the top of my class:

`#import "SFHFKeychainUtils.h"`

I use the following in a method:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *appName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleNameKey];
[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:[loginData objectForKey:@"email"] andPassword:[loginData objectForKey:@"password"] forServiceName:appName updateExisting:TRUE error:&error];
```

I then add **Security.framework** through 
Targets > Build Phases > Link Binary

Then when I go to build i get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SFHFKeychainUtils", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Which is the same error I got before linking Security.framework. I have cleaned and rebuilt my project but cant think of anything else to try.

Comment: Do you have SFHFKeychainUtils.m (implementation, not header) at your target's Compile Sources stage ? Sometimes the files added to the project are not being added there automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

squarefrog,

Make sure you've added the `SFHFKeychainUtils.m` to your application target. You can check this by either selecting the file in the left pane of XCode and looking at the "Target Membership" section or by going to Project->Your Target->Build Phases->Compile Sources and checking if the `SFHFKeychainUtils.m` is added to the list of files.

Let me know if this helped!

Cheers,
Pawel

Comment: Completely forgot about that step. Xcode doesn't seem to add them automatically anymore. Thanks for saving my sanity.

Comment: As a side note - after I did this, the app would compile for iOS fine, but would not run in the simulator. If you experience this problem go to `Build Settings > Framework Search Paths`, and remove whatever is there.